# How do you convert different bases?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know how to convert any number into base 10 by using the below method.

Write (6712)base 8 in base 10.
Ans: $6 \times 8^3 + 7 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 8^1 + 2 \times 8^0 = 3530_{10} $

However, I am not sure how to convert a number in base 10 or a different base into a number in a different base (other than 10).

For example, write (101)base 2 in base 8.

Is there a formula to solve such questions? Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [General conversion answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1291533/206402)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From base $2$ to base $8$ is pretty easy - simply convert each $3$ digits into a single digit as follows:

- $000\rightarrow0$
- $001\rightarrow1$
- $010\rightarrow2$
- $011\rightarrow3$
- $100\rightarrow4$
- $101\rightarrow5$
- $110\rightarrow6$
- $111\rightarrow7$

If the number of digits is not a multiple of $3$, then add $1$ or $2$ leading zeros.

For example: $(011|001|101|001|010)_2=(31512)_8$.

---

From base $10$ to base $b$, use the following algorithm (shown in an example):

$567382_{10}=?_{8}$

- $567382\div8=70922+\frac{\color\red6}{8}$
- $70922\div8=8865+\frac{\color\red2}{8}$
- $8865\div8=1108+\frac{\color\red1}{8}$
- $1108\div8=138+\frac{\color\red4}{8}$
- $138\div8=17+\frac{\color\red2}{8}$
- $17\div8=2+\frac{\color\red1}{8}$
- $2\div8=0+\frac{\color\red2}{8}$

$567382_{10}=2124126_{8}$

---

If the initial base is not $10$, then you might have a hard time performing the $\div$ operation.

Since you already know how to convert from any base to base $10$, the general method is:

- Convert from the source base to base $10$ (as you already know)
- Convert from base $10$ to the target base (as shown in the example above)

Comment: I understand that. However, how would we solve it if we were given larger bases to deal? Is there a specific formula? Algorithm?

Comment: @anonymous: See updated answer.

Comment: Does that algorithm work for all bases?

Comment: @anonymous: See updated answer.

Comment: I have done a some questions from my textbook and am quite confident with it now. Thank you!

Comment: @anonymous: You're welcome :)